# Wordpress post_meta into JSON

Tags: php, json, wordpress

Maybe someone know how to encode some wordpress post_meta values into JSON file?
Tried like this 'x' => get_post_meta($post->ID,'geo_latitude',true),

I have table postmeta where some of key_meta have some values like geo_latitude and geo_langitude.. how to take it into json file?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

```
$meta = get_post_meta( $post->ID );
$data = json_encode($meta);
file_put_contents('json.txt',$data);
$read = json_decode(file_get_contents('json.txt'));
```